# How to access/choose calender values using xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to choose/select a particular date of a month and my screen displays multiple months on the screen (for example - JAN, FEB, MAR ).

Here is my tree structure:

```
div class="MeCalendarMonthDay MeCalendarWeekDay3" 
style="width:14.285714285714286%;height:50px">
<span>14</span>
<input type="hidden" value="Wed Aug 14 2013">
</div>
```

I tried the below options ( I am using selenium test automation tool )

```
calender = driver.findElement(By.className("MeCalendarMonthNotSingle"));
date = calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MeCalendarMonthName' and    
contains(.='Aug 2013')]"));
date.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'Tue Aug 13 2013']")).click();
```

Also I tried

```
date.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='hidden' and value = 'Tue Aug 13   
2013']")).click();
```

But, none of the above options are working for me. Can you please help me ?

The below option at times works.However, it fails to recognize the month as there are
multiple months displayed on the page.

```
date.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='13']")).click();`
```

Comment: A lot of inconsistencies in your  input and your code or is it just me? `Wed Aug 14 2013` does not equal `Tue Aug 13 2013`.

Comment: Sorry, However, your solution works perfectly alright. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some XPath solutions. Don't exactly know which element you want to be returned:

Selects on `@class` from `<div>` and `@value` from `<input>`. Returns the `<input>` element:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')]/input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]"));
```

Selects on `@class` from `<div>` and `@value` from `<input>`. Returns the `<div>` element:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay') and input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]]"));
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]]"));
```

Selects on `@class` from `<div>` and `text()` from `<span>` and `@value` from `<input>`. Returns the `<input>` element:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay') and span = 14]/input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]"));
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][span = 14]/input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]"));
```

Selects on `@class` from `<div>` and `text()` from `<span>` and `@value` from `<input>`. Returns the `<div>` element:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay') and input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')] and span = 14]"));
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][span=14][input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]]"));
```

If you want the `<span>` element to be returned:

Selects on `@class` from `<div>` and `@value` from `<input>`. Returns the `<span>` element:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]]/span"));
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay') and input[contains(@value, 'Aug 14')]/span"));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. The solution works perfectly alright and very elaborate answers. In addition , can I parameterise date ? date = Aug 14 - calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay') and input[contains(@value, date)]/span")); ?

Comment: You can parameterise it. It is python you use? First declare the variable 'date="Aug 14"' then you can use it as you did in your comment.